# Centering a YouTube video within a background image

Tags: html

I am attempting to center an embedded video within a background image. You can see the background image and YouTube video are not centering within each other. Here is a link to the example: http://wanalift.org/learning-center

I did this by placing the embed of the video within a div and centering it. I also attempted to center the background image. Here is the code I am using:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"> 
     <iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LBJJ4s6VAz4?rel=0"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <div style="text-align: center;"> 
              <iframe src="http://wanalift.org/wp-content/themes/wanalift/images/Video_Player_Background.png" frameborder="0" width="660" height="380"></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
```

What am  I missing to center the video within the background image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the background image of the div containing the video to the image

```
<div style="text-align: center;background-image: url(http://wanalift.org/wp-content/themes/wanalift/images/Video_Player_Background.png);">...</div>
```